# CRUD actions on a Devise User model - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, crud

I'm working on a project that has a `User` Devise model and an `Admin` Devise model, and I want an `Admin` to be able to perform CRUD on the User model.

I've set up both Devise models following the Devise Wiki's [How to Setup Multiple Devise User Models](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models) guide (including step 4 - exposing the scoped controllers).

This has given me the Devise views and controllers for `confirmations`, `passwords`, `registrations`, `sessions` and `unlocks`, but no `users_controller` to add CRUD actions to.

Could I simply create a `users_controller` and make sure it uses the correct `users` table in the database, or should I add CRUD actions to the `registrations_controller`?

Is the above advisable, or is there a more elegant way of setting up a CRUD interface for an `Admin` to be able to manage the `User` model?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have all controller for CRUD of admin. right ?

Answer (score 1):

Devise works only with sign_up/sign_in process. It assumes not only simple user creation, but some more things, like email sending.
So if you want to create/update/destroy users you need to create separate `UsersController`. It is better to add an `admin` namespace to it